# Comparing objects memory address, Java

Tags: java, object, boolean

```
Robot r1,r2,r3;
r1=new Robot("Huey",2,3);
r2=new Robot("Louie",5,4);
r3=new Robot("Louie",5,4);
r1=r2;
r2=r3;
r3=r1;
System.out.print(r1==r2);
```

So this program prints false, but I thought it would print true. Its asking if the memory address of r1 is the same as r2. Well r1 is set to equal r2, then r2 is changed to r3, but that shouldn't matter, right? It's still r2 we're comparing it to.

Comment: I say this often, but this would be obvious if you used a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Memory address? Java? Actually, `r1==r2` is asking if r1 and r2 both refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see the situation after each assignment

```
// r1 - Huey, r2 - Louie1, r3 - Louie2
r1=r2;
// r1 - Louie1, r2 - Louie1, r3 - Louie2
r2=r3;
// r1 - Louie1, r2 - Louie2, r3 - Louie2
r3=r1;
// r1 - Louie1, r2 - Louie2, r3 - Louie1
```

In the end, `r1` is the first 'Louie' instance (former `r2`) and `r2` is the second.

PS I assume I don't need to comment why `new Robot("Huey",2,3) == new Robot("Huey",2,3)` returns false.

Comment: Oh ok nice, so thats how I'd break it down then. Now when you have in the comments r1 - Louie1, that would be read as r1 points to Louie1 correct?

Comment: @fprime Yes, 'points' is a good word here. I.e., `System.out.print(r1==r3);` should print `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Trace the logic Through

```
r1 = Huey
r2 = Louie#1
r3 = Louie#2

r1 = Louie#1
r2 = Louie#2
r3 = Huey
```

does r1 == r2?  r1 is Louie#1, r2 is Louie#2

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize your snippet as:

```
Initial        r1 -> Obj1, r2 -> Obj2, r3 -> Obj3

After r1=r2    r1 -> Obj2, r2 -> Obj2, r3 -> Obj3 ( Obj1 ready for GC)

After r2=r3    r1 -> Obj2, r2 -> Obj3, r3 -> Obj3

After r3=r1    r1 -> Obj2, r2 -> Obj3, r3 -> Obj2
```

Clearly at the end `r1` and `r2` do not refer to the same object hence comparing them gives `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, variables pointing to objects are references. When r1=r2 is executed r1 is pointing the same object r2 was pointing to and after r2=r3 then r2 is pointing the same object r3 was pointing to.  So you are comparing the second Robot object´s memory address with the third Robot object´s memory address, and they are different. If you want semantic equalilty your Robot class must override equals() and hashCode(), take a look at: http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html

Answer (score 1):

In `r1=new Robot("Huey",2,3);` line memory manager takes some memory from heap (for example it is M1 memory) and writes there `Robot("Huey",2,3)`. And r1 refers to M1.

In `r2=new Robot("Louie",5,4);` line memory manager takes some memory from heap (for example it is M2 memory) and writes there  `Robot("Louie",5,4)`. And r2 refers to M2.

And finally in `r3=new Robot("Louie",5,4);` line memory manager takes some memory from heap (for example it is M3 memory) and writes there  `Robot("Louie",5,4)`. And r3 refers to M3.

After `r1=r2` command r1 refers to M2. After `r2=r3` command r2  refers to M3. And after `r3=r1` command r2 refers to M2.

And when you write `System.out.print(r1==r2)` it tries to compare what does r1 and r2 refer, it means M2 and M3. That's why it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You are compare two different Robot objects. Use equals that must be redefined in Robot class.